# Wordpress white screen and The plugin generated 6 characters of unexpected output

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and its show me white screen right now. There is one plugin of theme which I deactivate website start working and after activating the plugin I got this message on my admin dashboard

> The plugin generated 6 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin

This plugin is main plugin of the website's theme and my website is nothing without this plugin. I try few things regarding this issue

I try to remove the unwanted space from php tag of the plugin files.
I try to add

```
ob_start();

ob_clean();
```

in my plugins php file. Nothing works for me. Anybody have any idea? what I have to do?

Comment: Check the error log file of your site. You will get error or warning from that.

Comment: @akshaysaxena last warning message was on 16-Jun-2017 there is no message in today's date

Answer (score 0):

Once you add this, the blank screen will now have errors, warnings, and notices. These may be able to help you determine the root cause.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
?>
```

Comment: I got nothing on page its still blank

Comment: index.php me likh kar dekho

Comment: abhi bhi blank hai bhai

Comment: kon sa plugin use kiya hai?

Comment: theme ka apna plugin hai tourmaster usko deactivate karte hi website chal padti hai

Comment: tumne max size wagerah set kar rakhi hai?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149812/discussion-between-anand-pandey-and-azad-chouhan).